# Try, except, else not doing what I expect it to in fetching post data (Django)

Tags: python, django, post, try-except

I'm using Django 1.6 and Python 2.7.  Basically I am making a voting application and I'm trying to get the selected choice (a 'Citizen') from a radio button, then instantiate a 'Best Citizen' using the selected Citizen as a one-to-one key.

Here are my models:

```
class Citizen(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    can_best = models.BooleanField(False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Best_Citizen(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    citizen = models.OneToOneField(Citizen)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^choose_best/$', views.choose_best, name='choose_best'),
    url(r'^(?P<citizen_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

My 'choose_best' view is not doing what I expect.  Apparently the try clause is evaluating OK, but else is never run.  I'm using a print test and it doesn't show up in my command promt.

```
def index(request):

    citizens = Citizen.objects.all()
 #   citizens = get_list_or_404(Citizen)
    for citizen in citizens: 
        if citizen.votes >= 3:
            citizen.can_best = True
            citizen.save()

    return render(request, 'best_app/index.html', {'citizens':citizens})

def detail(request, citizen_id):

    try:
        citizen = Citizen.objects.get(pk=citizen_id)
    except Citizen.DoesNotExist:
        print "raise Http404"
    return render(request, 'best_app/detail.html', {'citizen':citizen})
 #   return HttpResponse("You're looking at poll %s." % citizen.name)

def choose_best(request):

    best_candidates = Citizen.objects.filter(can_best=True)     # narrow down the candidates for best citizen to those with >= 3 votes

    if request.method == 'POST':

        try:
            selected_choice = best_candidates.get(pk=request.POST['citizen'])
        except (KeyError, Citizen.DoesNotExist):

            return render(request, 'index.html')
        else:   
            print "selected choice is: ", selected_choice
            Best_Citizen.objects.all().delete()                 # Current best citizen is deleted to make way for new best citizen
            new_best = Best_Citizen(citizen=selected_choice)    
            new_best.save()
            return render(request, 'best_app/index.html', {'new_best':new_best})

    else:
        return render(request, 'best_app/choose_best.html', {'best_candidates':best_candidates})
```

I expect the browser to return to index.html, but the final else clause is evaluated right away.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks for anyone's help.

Comment: You're not performing a POST. See your HTTP logs.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  Now I rebooted and for some reason the else clause is evaluating.  It does show a POST request in my logs.  The print test is also running.  However, the render to 'best_app/index.html' still doesn't evaluate.  The browser renders the final else clause and goes to 'choose_else.html' instead.